# Finding existing tickets before opening new ones on trac

Tags: trac

We're using Trac as the task management tool at the project we work in. However, Trac search is maybe not the most intuitive search out there, and we end up having multiple duplicates as the reporters can't effectively find if there already is a reported ticket of the question he or she found.

Stack Overflow's "Related Questions" concept is great and works magnificently! I was wondering if someone has heard of some similar plugin to Trac, or if you have solved this problem some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For trac stuff always turn to [trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org)

Here is one it looks right for you, [DuplicateTicketSearchPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DuplicateTicketSearchPlugin): Provides an AJAX-style lookup for duplicate tickets, used on the New Ticket page. Automatically searches for related tickets based on the summary field.

Comment: As a pointer to those who are looking for the same: I installed the plugin and it went well. The problem is that the tickets in my trac  are not written in English, but in Finnish, which is a heavily agglutinative language. The plugin doesn't really ever find duplicates of this reason. It will probably work a lot better (or at least I hope so) for English-spoken tracs, but I haven't tested this myself.